# RavenDB exception on query - Method not found: 'Void Raven.Abstractions.Data.IndexQuery.set_DefaultField(System.String)'

Tags: c#, ravendb

I am getting the following exception during the foreach loop of refresh model as it tries to enumerate through the results retreived by the query. I have not been able to find anything relating to this error anywhere else on the internet. Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

> System.MissingMethodException was unhandled
>
> > Message=Method not found: 'Void Raven.Abstractions.Data.IndexQuery.set_DefaultField(System.String)'.
> >     Source=Raven.Client.Lightweight
> >
> > StackTrace:
> >
> > > at Raven.Client.Document.AbstractDocumentQuery`2.GenerateIndexQuery(String query)
> > >
> > > at Raven.Client.Document.AbstractDocumentQuery`2.InitializeQueryOperation(Action`2 setOperationHeaders) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\AbstractDocumentQuery.cs:line 399
> > >
> > > at Raven.Client.Document.AbstractDocumentQuery`2.InitSync() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\AbstractDocumentQuery.cs:line 434
> > >
> > > at Raven.Client.Document.AbstractDocumentQuery`2.get_QueryResult() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Document\AbstractDocumentQuery.cs:line 421
> > >
> > > at Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryProviderProcessor`1.ExecuteQueryTProjection in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Linq\RavenQueryProviderProcessor.cs:line 1263
> > >
> > > at Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryProviderProcessor`1.Execute(Expression expression) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Linq\RavenQueryProviderProcessor.cs:line 1244
> > >
> > > at Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryProvider`1.Execute(Expression expression) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Linq\RavenQueryProvider.cs:line 138
> > >
> > > at Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryProvider`1.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Linq\RavenQueryProvider.cs:line 195
> > >
> > > at Raven.Client.Linq.RavenQueryInspector`1.GetEnumerator() in c:\Builds\RavenDB-Stable\Raven.Client.Lightweight\Linq\RavenQueryInspector.cs:line 97
> > >
> > > at AdminPanel.RefreshModel() in C:\AdminPanel\AdminPanel.xaml.cs:line 111

```
private void RefreshModel()
{
    MainModel.Movies.Clear();
    foreach (FriendlyName movie in App.Database.QueryAllMovies())
    {
        MainModel.Movies.Add(movie);
    }
}

public IEnumerable<FriendlyName> QueryAllMovies()
{
    using (var session = DocumentStore.OpenSession())
    {
        return session.Query<Movie, Movies_AsFriendlyName>().As<FriendlyName>();
    }
}

class Movies_AsFriendlyName : AbstractIndexCreationTask<Movie>
{
    public Movies_AsFriendlyName()
    {
        Map = movies => movies.Select(movie => new { Id = movie.Id, Name = movie.FileName });

        TransformResults = (database, movies) => movies.Select(movie => new { Id = movie.Id, Name = movie.FileName });
    }
}

public class FriendlyName
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public FriendlyName(string id, string name)
    {
        Id = id;
        Name = name;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Usually when you have something like this, you compiled against one version, but the dll it's trying to use is another.

I bet if you look at the versions between where the program is running and where it was compiled, they are different.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Working in Visual Studio, I clean, build, and then run. Do you mean different version of Raven?

Here's is my packages.config for NuGet:

    <packages>

      <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="4.0.8" />

      <package id="NLog" version="2.0.0.2000" />

      <package id="RavenDB" version="1.0.888" />

      <package id="RavenDB.Client" version="1.0.960" />

      <package id="RavenDB.Database" version="1.0.960" />

      <package id="RavenDB.Embedded" version="1.0.960" />
    </packages>

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to the weirdness of StackOverflow comment's. Here's what I was trying to say above.

In my NuGet packages.config file, RavenDB is using 1.0.888, but there's also 1.0.960 versions of RavenDB.Embedded, RavenDB.Database, and RavenDB.Client. I suppose that one thing that has changed between when this worked and when this stopped working was the introduction of the embedded package in addition to those other dependencies. Did I not do that right?

I was trying to make it so that a value in App.config could specify whether to use Embedded or Client raven instance. Is this possible?